# Find the parameter minimizing KL divergence

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

For discrete probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ defined on the same probability space, $\mathcal{X}$, the relative entropy from $Q$ to $P$ is defined  to be
$$
D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \| Q)=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \log \left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)
$$
Assume my two distributions are $P=[p, 0, \ldots,0, 1-p]$ and $Q=binomial(n,q)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) q^{k}(1-q)^{n-k}, \forall k \in \{0,1,2,...n\}$.

Both distributions have $n+1$ mass points. (The non-extreme probabilities are $0$ for $P$).

Can someone help me find the parameter $q$ which minimize $
D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \| Q)$?

Answer (score 0):

Here your probability space is $\mathcal X = \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$, so with the given distributions $P$ and $Q$ you Kullback-Leibler divergence simply rewrites
$$\begin{align}D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \| Q)&=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} P(x) \log \left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}} P(k) \log \left(\frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}\right)\\
&= p\log \left(\frac{p}{(1-q)^n}\right) + 0 +(1-p)\log \left(\frac{1-p}{q^n}\right)  \end{align} $$

Assuming $p=1-q$, this further simplifies to
$$\begin{align}D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \| Q)&= (1-q)\log \left(\frac{1}{(1-q)^{n-1}}\right)  +q\log \left(\frac{1}{q^{n-1}}\right) \\
&= (n-1) \cdot\left((1-q)\log\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right)  +q\log \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)\right)\end{align}$$

So finding the $q$ that minimizes $D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \| Q)$ is equivalent to finding the $q$ that minimizes
$$ (1-q)\log\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right)  +q\log \left(\frac{1}{q}\right) $$

Which you should be able to find.

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are not related.

Comment: If they are unrelated then you want to find q that maximizes
$$p\log \left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right) +(1-p)\log \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)$$
which should be doable too

Comment: Thanks. It implies $1-p=q$.